# Using excel Datasource test step that contains more than one Worksheet?

Tags: soapui

Is it possible to use one excel Datasource that contains more than one Worksheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an Excel file that contains more than one worksheet. But in soapUI in the `Worksheet` input field (in the configuration of the `DataSource`) you can only specify one worksheet...

What you can do is to specify the name of the worksheet in a property (e.g. `${#TestCase#worksheet}`) and then change the value of this property if you want to change the worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of SoapUI pro (4.5.1) has a field in the Data Source setup screen which allows you to provide the exact name of the sheet without setting up a property tag.